# Scala Implicit generators

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, implicit, scalaz, scalaz7

If I have an implicit from `A` to `B`, how can I auto-get implicits from `F[A]` to `F[B]`?

For example, if I have `implicit toInt[A](l: List[A]) = l.size` and now I want to have an implicit from `(List[A], Int)` to `(Int, Int)` which reuses the `toInt` implicit. Is that even possible in Scala?

Comment: Only `List[T]` or any collection/functor?

Comment: I was just using `List[T]` as an example. So, yes, any functor..

Comment: Btw the `List[A] => Int` conversions looks *really* smelly... I would not use anything like that in my code.

Comment: I agree it it smelly - a better but short example to get the point of the question across would be nice.

Comment: If you are writing new Scala code you simply should not be using implicit conversions 99.9% of the time—type classes and implicit classes are almost always a much better approach.

Answer (score 4):

Implicits can use other implicits to convert values. So given your `toInt`:

```
implicit def toInt[A](l: List[A]): Int = l.size
```

We can define an implicit conversion for converting the first element of a 2-tuple to `Int`, e.g. `(List[Int], Int)` to `(Int, Int)`:

```
implicit def tupleConvert[A <% Int, C](x: (A, C)): (Int, C) = (x._1, x._2)
```

The `A <% Int` declares a view bound, requiring that an implict conversion from `A` to `Int` be available in the calling scope.

It might seem like the following would be possible:

```
implicit def tupleConvert2[A <% B, B, C](x: (A, C)): (B, C) = (x._1, x._2)
```

allowing us to convert any 2-tuple of type `(A, C)` to `(B, C)` given a conversion from `A` to `B`. However, because of the way Scala resolves type parameters for implicits this does not work*.

*(I think this may be a bug, it looks a lot like SI-2046, which is a duplicate of SI-3340, which is still open)